# Image Processing on Custom ImageView and saving the modified image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using a Custom ImageView. In its onDraw I do some processing by using the canvas which is like drawing line, bitmaps based on user touch.

To save the resultant snapshot when the user want to save the image, we are using drawingCache

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true;
Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, 
       imageView.getHeight(), imageView.getWidth(),
       matrix, true).compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95,
       new FileOutputStream(file));
```

Of course I can use this to get the actual image while user presses save but the image does not contain any of the processing done on the imageView.

```
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, 
        bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(),
        matrix, true).compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95,
                    new FileOutputStream(file));
```

Problem:
The size of the image saved is the size of the imageView which is fullscreen but depends on the device. For smaller screen size phones it goes down to 240 X 320.

Question:

a. Is it possible to get a decent size image irrespective of the device screen size?

b. Is it possible to do Image Processing directly on the Image that is being used in the Custom ImageView?

Thanks in anticipation!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an alternative would be use the Canvas class to do some of your drawing and image display: [javadoc: android.graphics.Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).

The ImageView class is not the best when images need to "refreshed" often.

If you decide to stick to ImageView, don't create the bitmap using the ImageView's dimensions. Retain the aspect ratio of the image, and compose your bitmap according to the big dimensions you need. The imageView will shrink it (if needed) to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap b, int newWidth, int newHieght, boolean filter);
```

and to get a bitmap from resources use

```
     Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(..)
```

you can then use

```
    ImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
```

to set the new bitmap to the imageview

Comment: I guess you did not get the question. Its not about scaling the image and displaying but the other way round